# How many IP addresses have been question-banned so far?

Tags: support, post-ban, statistics

How many IP addresses have been question-banned from Stack Overflow so far? Is it 10,000 or more like 100,000, or even 1,000,000?

Does anyone have any idea what the number is, or at least the order of magnitude?

Just curious.

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: I want this, and more - full list of banned IPs! preferably updated on a daily basis

Comment: What on earth is wrong with you people? Why is this off-topic? @Infinite you know full well that this isn't in SEDE, so this is a legitimate request for data. Can everyone please re-read [the description of what meta's about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)?

Comment: @Ben: So what's to discuss here? Also, how is it useful?

Comment: What @ben said. Here is a similar question on MSE, well received, answered by Shog9: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172300/what-happens-to-folks-who-get-question-banned-by-and-large

Comment: @Ben: Yes, I know it isn't in SEDE. This question does not match any of the criteria mentioned in the linked post. This question looks off-topic to me. It's a data-request about data related to **categorization by IP addresses** which isn't supposed to be public. All that can be exposed, is already exposed in SEDE. Data is critical, and those who request it should have valid grounds for the request. Anyways, I am not interested to debate the validity of this request. Hope SE devs don't oblige this request.

Comment: I din't see a reason from OP why we should know this. If there is a useful case to it, I could agree on it, but if it is just a 'how many pencils does Tim have on his desk' question, I don't see the usefulness.

Comment: @user000001: it is not a similar question. The answer just shows some data to make a point. The data isn't the answer itself.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well nobody has said why requesting for statistics about Stack Overflow is off topic on meta. As for the question, sashoalm could probably be more convincing on why he thinks the data is useful, but in any case the mods/devs are sure to see the question, so they will decide if they chose to answer/close or do nothing with it.

Comment: This is a valid request for stats, voting to reopen.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166942/statistics-on-number-of-users-being-post-banned (things migt have changed and a CM might share some raw stats thoguh)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, I hadn't seen the duplicate because it was in meta.stackexchange.com, and I was searching only in meta.stackoverflow.com. I always forget about the new site.

Comment: @sashoalm actually MSO is the new site, MSE exists for as long as Stack Exchange itself exists.

Comment: Can we please have their names and addresses too?

Comment: @chiastic-security:  There's nothing you could do with that information.

Comment: @Makoto We could go round there and duff them up.

Comment: @user000001: that is a very different question. The question you linked asks about how the site works (so, what happens to banned users?). This asks how many users have been banned, see the difference?

Comment: @nico: I agree the questions are different in that regard. However, even though It does ask that, the asnwer in fact explains how the site works. I don't think that Brad's answer is delete worthy, but I 'll refrain from reopening this for a second time. Maybe someone should ask a new meta-meta question asking if this should open or closed :)

Comment: @user000001: if one asks "why is my codez not working?" and you give a perfect answer I will upvote your answer, but downvote and cast a close vote on the question. Why should this be different?

Comment: @nico: because "why is my codez not working?" is a close reason. Asking for stats about SO isn't necessarily off-topic, even if the stats are about banned users.

Comment: @user000001: exactly, it isn't **necessarily** off-topic. But, alas, in this case it is (re-read the description of what meta is, this does not classify as on-topic in **my** opinion). Anyway, no point in continuing discussing this, if you think this is on-topic you should indeed cast a re-open vote, actually I would encourage you to do so if you think this question is a good fit.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think there's a bit of a mistaken assumption in the question itself. The process is changing, but IPs don't get strictly question-banned, users do. There are ties between the question bans of users and IPs with the newer anti-recidivism measures (in an attempt to try to prevent new accounts by the same user from working around a question ban), but that's not a straight IP ban. Even moderators aren't exposed to how the actual process works here, but it's pretty clear it's not an indiscriminate IP ban on posts once people are question-banned.

Posting from certain IPs can be temporarily hobbled in a controlled manner to mitigate incoming spam or trolling, but that's different than question bans. Even then, IP-based blocks tend to be short-lived, so any stats that you'd get would be localized to a specific period of time. If we get attacked from [hundreds of accounts coming from Tor nodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222386/can-se-block-actions-from-tor-exit-nodes/222394#222394), those IPs might all be throttled at once, elevating the numbers at that point in time. Again, almost all of those IP-related restrictions would be related to spam or trolling attempts, and not question bans of legitimate users.

If you are asking about question-banned users, Shog9 has indicated that [over the last 120 days 25,087 accounts have hit the question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237534/stats-on-how-attempts-to-circumvent-so-question-blocks-impact-other-sites/237540#comment778904_237540) (if I interpret the time period on that comment correctly).