# Question Ban: Try to get out or make new account?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Currently I am banned from asking questions on SO after asking one unclear and one stupid question. I have been working furiously to get out from under this ban by answering questions and trying to be helpful, but it is extremely hard.

I am trying to decide: Would it ever be worth it to abandon my current account and create a new one?

Comment: Post bans are never handed out for just one post. Note that if you create a new account the system will still recognise you and severely throttle your new account too. Are you sure you haven't got other, deleted posts?

Comment: I'm quite sure. I have no deleted posts.

Comment: @RamsaySmith: your current *visible* questions are not enough to land you in a question ban. You probably forgot about some old posts that have long since been deleted by the system (you don't get notified of such deletions). Only a moderator can tell you about such posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is that IP based?

Comment: @simonzack: That's not known; the mechanisms by which the site recognises you are deliberately not documented. Please don't ask.

Comment: There are hints that various post bans and IPs do relate at some level.  [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269679/289086), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267028/289086), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181792/what-is-the-scopes-of-a-question-ban/181805#181805).  It would suggest that if multiple users from the same IP get a post ban, future users from the same IP will have increased difficulty of some sort.  And mods tend to take a dim view of people creating multiple accounts to try to get around bans and that gets ugly too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have deleted and downvoted questions dating back to August, but you've only been blocked from asking for less than an hour. It takes more time than that to get out of a post ban.

It is *not* recommended that you try to skirt the post ban by creating a second account. If you continue making low-quality posts on a second account, activity from both accounts will count against you. Instead, you're encouraged to try and improve posts on the existing account, answer questions, make useful edits, etc.

Comment: How would activity from both accounts count against you? How would Stack Overflow know the accounts are by the same person?

Comment: I've been banned for around six months now. They should make it three months for asking a new question, because the user would probably gain the understanding on how to make a good question